# Очередь для обработки сообщение telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Всем привет. PyTelegramBotApi не позволяет обрабатывать сообщение быстрее чем 30 сооб/сек (иначе ошибка 429). Встал вопрос: а как тогда защититься от спама злого юзверя? Код бота снизу:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('776550937:AAELEr0c3H6dM-9QnlDD-0Q0Fcd65pPyAiM')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start')

bot.polling()
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token, skip_pending=True)
```